# Is there a one-click way (either natively or via extension) to clear the cache in Google Chrome on a Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-cache

For development purposes I clear the cache a **lot** in Google Chrome and would like to be able to do it with a single click. Is this possible on Mac? I found the [Click&Clean](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod) extension, but that appears to be Windows-only.

For now, I can use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>; but a one-click method would be sweet!

Comment: Unless you’re using an older version, you can’t even use the Ctrl+Shift+Del combo anymore because they removed tabbed-options and replaced them with that stupid web-page implementation. Now, simply bringing up the *Clear Browsing Data* dialog to clear the cache with takes 2-4 seconds instead of 0.5 seconds. :roll:

Answer (score 2):

Add this bookmark to the bookmarks bar:

```
chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
```

Comment: +1 for the tip, but it's still not one-click. It's the same as <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Google Chrome extension [Cache Killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en) for one click cache clearing on a Mac. Red means cache normal, green means Cache Killer is enabled.